# How to add a TextChangeListener inside custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I created a custom `ListView` which every row contains a `TextView` and an `EditText`. Everything is working perfectly, but I just don't know where I should set the `TextChangeListener` to the `EditText` so that I can set/save the value entered. Here's my code:

RowItem.java

```
public class RowItem {

    private String title;
    private String value;

    public RowItem(String title, String value) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;
    List<RowItem> items;

    public CustomList(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        EditText txtValue;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.txtValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.txtValue.setText(rowItem.getValue());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your viewHolder to contain the row number of the row it points to.

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    EditText txtValue;
    int rowNumber;
}
```

set the rowNumber always

```
holder.txtValue.setText(rowItem.getValue());
holder.rowNumber = position;
```

Add your Custom adapter as a onFocusListener on the editText and get the rowNumber edited by the following code.

```
void onFocusChanged(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)v.getParentView().getTag();
    int rowNo = holder.rowNumber;
    //do rest of the stuff like modifying the array list.
}
```

However, I do think there should be an easier solution to it than this one.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about the `onFocusChanged`?

Comment: setOnFocusListener and View.OnFocusListener deals with the beginning and ending of focus just like Javascript. When your edit text is done with editing, onFocusChanged gets called.